# Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and $f: M\rightarrow N$ a diffeomorphism. Prove that the map $df:TM \rightarrow TN$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I am going through qualifying exam questions and I am stuck on this problem.  I don't think it should be too difficult, but I am having a lot of difficulty.  I am not even sure how to start.  Some hints would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and $f: M\rightarrow N$ a diffeomorphism.  Prove that the map $df:TM \rightarrow TN$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: The easiest way to show something is an isomorphism (in whatever context is appropriate) is to show that it has an inverse. Any other way you've been taught to show that something is an isomorphism is an advanced technique. Try the basics first.

Comment: Hint: the assignment $M \mapsto TM$ and $f \mapsto df$, defined for all smooth manifolds and smooth maps thereof, is a functor.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on my hint in the comments: you only have to prove that $d(fg) = df dg$ and that $d(1_M) = 1_{TM}$, then you should be able to figure out how a diffeomorphism induces an invertible linear map of tangent spaces.